# How to make Pinterest style list view?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, pinterest

I was trying to make a list view style "Pinterest"
But it must have considerable skill.
Because memory management should be required.
List-view structure of the adapter that you are currently viewing the object in memory.
For the invisible area and have to release the memory in the form of
I know that that is.
I worry about is how to use and customize how the adapter view.
Ask for help who knows a solution

Comment: [StaggeredGridView](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/)

Comment: @AdilSoomro I found a solution, but it occurred bug when I scroll up and down quickly at the bottom of each cell area, to deviate from the original location

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the arrangement of divisions.If so you can list divisions in the pinterest style using :- http://funscripts.popbild.com/jquery_popbild/

Its the easiest tutorial/project you can find on the internet for listing divisions in pinterest style.

Answer (score 0):

May be this library will help for you.

https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView